# how to hide "view more" button when all items is displayed in listview

Tags: jquery, html, css, vb.net

i want to hide "view more" button when all items is displayed in listview noting that it display 6 by 6 item , it working fine but i only want to hide the button when all rows is displayed, if there is a solution using jquery or in codebehind its fine both ways

here is the html

```
     <asp:ListView runat="server" ID="lstCareers">
                                <LayoutTemplate>
                                    <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" 
    ID="ItemPlaceHolder"></asp:PlaceHolder>
                                </LayoutTemplate>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:HyperLink runat="server" 
    ID="HyperLink1" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("PID")%>'>
                                        <li class="liCareers">
                                            <p class="Vacancies_title">
                                                <asp:Label runat="server" 
    ID="lblTitle" Text='<%#Eval("Title")%>'></asp:Label>
                                            </p>
                                            <p class="Vacancies_pref">
                                                <asp:Label runat="server" 
    ID="lblBrief" Text='<%#Eval("Brief")%>'></asp:Label>
                                            </p>
                                            <img 
    src="../../App_Themes/ThemeEn/Images/DetailsBtn.png" style="float: right;"/>
                                            <br />
                                        </li>
                                    </asp:HyperLink>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:ListView>
                        </ul>
                        <div style="clear: both"></div>
                        <center style="padding: 20px">

                            <div class="col-md-2" style="float: none !important;">

                            <a href="#" id="loadMore">

                        <asp:label runat="server" ID="lblReadMore" style="font-size: 18px;"></asp:label>
<img src="../../App_Themes/ThemeEn/Images/loadmoreImage.png"/>
                                </a>
                                </div>
                        </center>
```

here is the jquery responsible for slicing

```
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $(".liCareers").slice(0, 5).show();
            $("#loadMore").on('click', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $(".liCareers:hidden").slice(0, 4).slideDown();
                if ($(".liCareers:hidden").length == 0) {
                    $("#load").fadeOut('slow');
                }
                $('html,body').animate({
                    scrollTop
                    }, 1500);
            });
        });

    </script>
```

here is the css

```
    .liCareers {
            display: none;
            padding: 10px;
            border-width: 0 1px 1px 0;
            border-style: solid;
            border-color: #fff;
            box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #ccc;
            margin-bottom: 5px;
            background-color: #f1f1f1;
        }
```

here is the code behind

```
    Protected Sub fillNews()
        Try
            Using db As New EchoNewWebSiteClassLibrary.EchoNewWebSiteDataClassesDataContext
                Dim SelectedNews = From latestnews In db.SelectCareersBySiteID(SessionManager.CurrentSessionManager.SiteID)
                           Select latestnews
                lstCareers.DataSource = SelectedNews.ToList()
                lstCareers.DataBind()

            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

when you going to find the first-page record (0 to 6) and then you need to find next page record (7 to 12). If next page record exists then you declare a parameter (**IsMoreRecord**). and pass the true or false value in it. and check if
(**IsMoreRecord**) true then button visible otherwise button visible false.